# Wiki for [nutrition] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Given our discussion of nutrition related questions, I have written a wiki for the tag.  Since this is a complex area, I invite everyone to review.

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/nutrition/info

Comment: thank you for the nice write-up!

Comment: Very nice! That's an accurate description of where we draw the line. I just made a few small tweaks to the formatting and the language ("bad" vs. "off-topic" questions).

Comment: Just to nitpick: Can't "Which types of food contain oligosaccharides?" be seen as a not-constructive question?

Comment: @Mien I think the key there is *types* - just asking for a general category not a list of everything?

Comment: Sure, I wasn't totally sure. In my opinion, wikis should be 100% clear. Nevertheless, OP did a really good job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think given that three mods have looked at it, we can say woohoo, good job! In addition to Aaronut's tweaks, I mentioned in the excerpt that "is this healthy" questions are off topic, on the off chance that people as they tag their questions do see that.

Comment: I am accepting only so the community process won't keep bumping this to the top.